# Fineract doesn't start in mac Mojave

Tags: mifos, apache-fineract

I followed exact same step as per [1] and when I execute

**./gradlew tomcatRunWar**

Process didn't work after 92%

16:14:48.912 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Established shared JMS Connection: ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:Gayans-MacBook-Pro.local-58639-1559299488784-1:1,clientId=null,started=false}
16:14:48.971 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.f.i.c.b.WarWebApplicationInitializer - Started WarWebApplicationInitializer in 58.585 seconds (JVM running for 141.561)
The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String org.apache.fineract.portfolio.self.savings.api.SelfSavingsApiResource.template(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), should not consume any entity.
Started Tomcat Server
The Server is running at http://localhost:8080/fineract-provider

> Building 92% > :tomcatRunWar

[1] https://github.com/apache/fineract

Answer (score 1):

`./gradlew tomcatRunWar` is actually a way to run the Fineract App in Dev mode. The logs you pasted shows Fineract is actually doing the right thing by starting up in Dev mode. What you can do now is get the web app here: https://github.com/openMF/community-app, build it using the instructions in the read me and try to login to the Fineract backend using username: mifos, password: password